# What are those bumps on top of the Antonov-225?

Tags: feature-identification, antonov-225

What are those bumps on top of the Antonov-225? What are they for? And what are they called?

[image]

Comment: "The smaller semi-spherical domes further aft were caused by passengers not wearing seatbelts during turbulent conditions." -- [retardo montalban](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/42319/retardo-montalban).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to the [Airliners.net forum](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=736217), they are [fairings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_fairing) that cover [hardpoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardpoint) used for attaching outsize loads.

> Outsize loads that cannot fit into the capacious cabin (including Buran and Energiya components) are carried 'piggyback', the load supported on two main attachments above the center section. These supports and other smaller ones along the fuselage top are faired over when not in use.

The text is quoted from aeronautics.ru ([web archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20020325040618/http://www.aeronautics.ru/archive/vvs/an225-01.htm)).

Please note that the two large ones were **not** used for carrying the Buran space shuttle, as shown in the photo posted below. (More pictures [here](http://www.buran-energia.com/mriya-antonov/mriya-photos.php?file_dbt_=52).)

[image: Buran on top of the An-225]

Comment: Is there any evidence of them ever being used outside of the Buran program? Or a photo of them being used with the Buran?

Comment: I don't know about actual use. There's a schematic [here](http://www.buran-energia.com/mriya-antonov/mriya-desc.php) that shows other loads mounted on top.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I really want to know what the red teardrop shaped tank is, with some weird mini-buran?!

Comment: Had I scrolled further I would have realized that it is the MAKS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAKS_(spacecraft)